# Fixed function of setprecision() is sticky

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main() {
    float a = 456.123456789;
    std::cout << a << "\n"; //State 1
    std::cout << "fixed " << fixed << a << "\n"; //State 2
    std::cout << a << "\n"; //State 3
}
```

Output:

```
456.123 //State 1
fixed 456.123444 //State 2
456.123444 //State 3
```

What I want to do is switch back to state 1, so how can I do that? I tried a couple of things based on http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/ and all failed.

Comment: What does *fixed state* mean?

Comment: Write  a function.

Comment: note: all of the maniuplators are sticky except for `setw`

Comment: @wallyk On line 3 I want to be able to print out w/e that just got printed on line 1 and not the same thing as printed on line 2.

Comment: @M.M I think setw() is also sticky.

Comment: @Shayan try `std::cout << ',' << std::setw(6) << 1 << ',' << 1;`

Comment: Use `std::cout << defaultfloat << a << "\n";`. It will unset `floatfield`.

Comment: @abdullah that worked like a charm, better answer than on the duplicate page.